# How do I use Firebase as an opendID provider in Unity?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, authentication, openid-connect

I got the user to login using the Firebase SDK inside my Unity app
But I want to use some features inside Unity Gaming Services (UGS), and for that, the user must be logged in. The main reason I'm using Firebase to authentication is that it has password recovery already and the players management is easier there than in UGS.
Now I want to authenticate the user automatically in Unity Gaming Services with the Firebase user_ID or something like that, but I'm stuck at adding the Identity provider. Like, what is the Client ID and the Issuer URL??? Is the issuer URL the same for everyone like an API endpoint and the Client ID is the only unique parameter? If that's so, where can I find these parameters? I can't find anywhere and I don't see any examples when googling or searching in Youtube

I tried to find some API endpoints for Firebase and Google authentication, and used the web api key in the firebase project settings and the oAuth2 client id in my service account but it doesn't work. As I said, I don't even know what is that Client ID and the Issuer URL fields. [Adding Identity Provider Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mkrg.png)

Also when I tried to add, it says that I have invalid parameters but don't specify which fields are invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you read the Unity documentation, you can find the answer to your question. Here is the related documentation [link](https://docs.unity.com/ugs/en-us/manual/authentication/manual/platform-signin-google#Sign_in_a_returning_player_or_create_new_player).

Basically, you need to get the user's token from Firebase. Then you should authenticate with the Unity gaming service. Here is the example:

```
async Task SignInWithGoogleAsync()
{
    try
    {
        string idToken = await FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.CurrentUser.TokenAsync(); //get token
        await AuthenticationService.Instance.SignInWithGoogleAsync(idToken);
        Debug.Log("SignIn is successful.");
    }
    catch (AuthenticationException ex)
    {
        // Compare error code to AuthenticationErrorCodes
        // Notify the player with the proper error message
        Debug.LogException(ex);
    }
}
```